# How to use ground/1?

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm a complete beginner with Prolog and I wanted to know how to use `ground/1`.

At the moment I have this code:

```
intertwine([], [], []).
intertwine([E|Es], Fs, [E|Gs]) :- intertwine(Es, Fs, Gs).
intertwine(Es, [F|Fs], [F|Gs]) :- intertwine(Es, Fs, Gs).
```

But when I try to call this in the shell:

```
intertwine([1,2],X,[1,a,2,b]).
```

I get the right answer `X=[a,b]`, but the query doesn't end, as if it thinks there is another answer left.  So, I press ";" and I get "false" as output.  I read in another question's answer that I should use `ground/1`  to check whether the third list is already completely instantiated to handle the case.

Thing is, being a complete beginner, I have no clue how to do that.  So is there someone kind enough to explain to me how ground works and how I can use it to check instantiation of a specific parameter and use that to not have the code check for an answer that isn't there?

Answer (score 2):

That behaviour is completely OK.  Sometimes, Prolog is able to figure out that there is no further solution, and sometimes not.  The details do not make a difference to what is described.  Consider:

```
?- X = 1 ; 2 = 3.
   X = 1
;  false.
```

Here, it is evident to us that `2 = 3` is not a solution, still Prolog asks us to continue.

BTW, instead of ; you can also press SPACE to get the next solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like false said, this behavior is really ok. `ground/1` predicate isn't related to that question actually.

> to not have the code check for an answer that isn't there?

[Cut](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0) can be helpful here, if I get your question right.

```
intertwine([], [], []).
intertwine([E|Es], Fs, [E|Gs]) :- intertwine(Es, Fs, Gs), !.
intertwine(Es, [F|Fs], [F|Gs]) :- intertwine(Es, Fs, Gs), !.
```

So you've got your single answer.

```
?- intertwine([1,2],X,[1,a,2,b]).
X = [a, b].

?-
```

Comment: @Dimitri: intertwine(Xs,Ys,[1]). Should have two solutions, not one. There is a simple rule of thumb: A cut alone without any mode related tests almost always cuts aways valid solutions.

Comment: That's right. Actually I'm not fully getting what OP is really want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [ground/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ground/1), to check the instatiation of a parameter you should consider using [var/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=var/1) (or the related nonvar/1). var/1 it's the fundamental *metapredicate* that extends the power of Prolog beyond what's know as the *pure* subset of language. It allows to reason about the program itself, selecting appropriate behaviour depending on the 'state' of such fundamental entities as variables.

A (very) simple use of these metapredicate, from a practical programming POV, allows to implement *default* values for specific parameters: for instance

```
%%  gunzip(+Gz, ?Ex) is det.
%
%   uncompress the file Gz in Ex
%   if Ex is var strip .gz extension
%
gunzip(Gz, Ex) :-
    (   nonvar(Ex)
    ->  true
    ;   atom_codes(Gz, Cs),
        phrase(string(ExCs), Cs, ".gz"),
        atom_codes(Ex, ExCs)
    ),
    gzopen(Gz, read, I, [type(binary)]),
    setup_call_cleanup(open(Ex, write, O, [type(binary)]),
               copy_stream_data(I, O),
               ( close(I), close(O) )
              ).
```

if we call gunzip('file.gz', F), F get instanced (hopefully) with the name of inflated data.